# Is `Union` of strings and `string` achievable?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is they're a way to have an `union` of `string` type that accepts some specific strings AND `string` ?

```
type AcceptsWithString =
 | 'optionA'
 | 'optionB'
 | 'optionC'
 | string
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxnCZgGcDqBLYALA9gV2AGVgAnDAOwHMoBeAKCgB8oByXZDXCmVxl9p24AhPszYdgXCgGE%209UJFgIkqTDhLlqdfhKE8xAydNG7BU7nN0oylKvXpxuNqAHcseQprsAuZYmR0DwJiW21aPQsDR2dgNw9vaj94ALUEsJoI1gpcKABDQlynAFswABsIKNYgA)

The aim here is to have a type that offer auto completion for inputs (list can be long and we can make errors easily in some cases) AND also any string ?

Comment: No. The generic `string` will "eat" any specific string :)

Comment: In your playground I am still getting autocompletion when trying something with `AcceptsWithString`, for any specified strings.  Seems to be working as you expect?

Comment: @SethLutske o_O ? Are you sure ?? Maybe you have seen all strings that are type within the file but it's not auto completion proposed in this cas.

Comment: @SethLutske is probably poking in the first constant, – the one without `string`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky no workaround ? Sometimes you have such union which might hold 100 items or more and auto completion can become very handy in this case .... :/

Comment: There are techniques to write lots of properties faster, but you still have to write them down anyway, – `string` won't help (only harm, actually)

Comment: I'm typing `const thing: AcceptsWithString = 'optionA'`, as as I type the value, I definitely get autocompletion for the specified values, but no error if I deviate from the specified values...the exact desired behavior...?

Comment: @SethLutske Oh, right, that doesn't come from TypeScript, that comes from the editor itself. Try creating several unrelated strings (variables), – they will be suggested too

Comment: @zedryas The workaround would be to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), i.e. "if _some condition_ then it's `"a" | "b" | …`, else `string`"

Comment: There are good news if you need to use this type for function argument. BEcause in this case it is possible to get autocomplete. Otherwise I have a bad news. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/N9ypJN)

Comment: @SethLutske [Here's what I mean](https://tsplay.dev/w66X6w) by "create variables"

Comment: thanks a lot @captain-yossarian - if you write the answer I'll validate it

Comment: @zedryas yes I see what you're saying.  Dang editor being too helpful!

Comment: @zedryas it seems that Nocholas Tower has a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do know of a trick which can be used to confuse the IDE into still showing individual strings as autocomplete suggestions. There's no guarantee that this will work for ever, but it works as of the current versions of typescript:

```
type AcceptsWithString =
 | 'optionA'
 | 'optionB'
 | 'optionC'
 | string & {}
```

`string & {}` doesn't have any properties that `string` doesn't already have, so you can still assign any string to this. But it confuses the editor enough that it can't be sure that `"optionA"` and the others are redundant, so it keeps showing them.

Comment: nice solution!!!!!!

Comment: nice one lol - thanks a lot ;)